QTabWidget cannot click on first tabs
I've created an interface on QT designer for an application made with QT5.12.
There are QTabWidgets with several tabs in other parts of this app. Except that I'm having a problem with the latest QTabWidget I've just created: the first tab and half of the second are not clickable but all the others can be clicked as if nothing had happened.
It's as if there were an area that couldn't be clicked at the beginning of the tabs.
Very similar to this old post but no answers : QTabWidget strange behaviour on mouse click
I tried a long time to check what is different between my other QTabWidget but I couldn't find any differences.
If you have a clue as to how to solve the problem, thank you very much.

Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please, try update your question with a [mre] so that we can help you out

Hi, I haven't found a way to reproduce it. Perhaps I while try de recreate it from scratch, but since it's a big interface, I wanted to avoid doing that.

You don't have to post all of your code, but at least some snippet in which you don't see the intended behavior. We can't help you fix your code if we do not see it.
Also, consider to [edit] with the errors you get, if any

The fact is that I haven't touched the code between the time I started to get the bug and now. I just edit the .ui to add severals tabs and got this problem. Before that, it worked perfectly.

That doesn't change what I was telling you: if we don't have the code in front of us, we don't know what we're talking about and therefore we can't help you. If you need, take a look at [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly

Ok, I've just worked out what the problem is. When I opened the window containing my tabs with this strange behaviour, I instantiated a class that inherited from a QWidget but without any interface, which blocked the focus of the first tabs. The non-clickable area looked like this in terms of dimensions:dimensions of strange non clickable behavior
To solve it I just had to replace QWidget by QObject!
